# How to can I obtain a matrix transpose by a Python script?

Tags: python, python-3.x, outofrangeexception

How to check matrix transpose?

Can my code be simplified with an available Python function? And why if I test my code with the following input I obtain the error **out of range**? :

Matrix 1 = 3 x 2
(1,1): 1
(1,2): 2
(2,1): 3
(2,2): 4
(3,1): 5
(3,2): 6

Matrix 2 = 3 x 2
(1,1): 1
(1,2): 4
(2,1): 2
(2,2): 5
(3,1): 3
(3,2): 6

```
lines_matrix_1 = int(input("input lines Matrix 1: "))
columns_matrix_1 = int(input("Input columns Matrix 1: "))

matrix_1 = [[0 for j in range(columns_matrix_1)] for i in range(lines_matrix_1)]
empty = ""

for i in range(lines_matrix_1):
    for j in range(columns_matrix_1):
        matrix_1[i][j] = int(input(f'lines {i + 1} columns {j + 1} Matrix 1: '))

lines_matrix_2 = int(input("input lines Matrix 2: "))
columns_matrix_2 = int(input("Input columns Matrix 1: "))

matrix_2 = [[0 for j in range(columns_matrix_2)] for i in range(lines_matrix_2)]
for i in range(lines_matrix_2):
    for j in range(columns_matrix_2):
        matrix_2[i][j] = int(input(f'lines {i + 1} columns {j + 1} Matrix 2: '))


for i in range(lines_matrix_1):
    for j in range(columns_matrix_1):
        if matrix_1[i][j] == matrix_2[j][i]:
            empty += str(matrix_1[i][j])
        else:
            continue

if len(empty) == lines_matrix_1 * columns_matrix_1:
    print('can transpose')
elif len(empty) != lines_matrix_1 * columns_matrix_1:
    print('can't transpose')
else:
    print('can't transpose')
```

thank you:))

Answer (score 0):

It is quite simple. If matrix 1 is (a, b) shape so matrix 2 should be (b, a). Here your first matrix is (3, 2) matrix so second matrix cant be (3, 2) again but (2, 3) and it will work. You can read more about transpose matrix [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transpose).

Comment: yes, but how to fix it in my code?

Comment: I dont really know what u want to do but if the error is outofrange so u just type in the lines_matrix_2 and columns_matrix_2 is 2 and 3 and it will work